# How to get a variable to keep a running total on Python?

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to get this function `take_input` to add to the total whenever the function is run. However, I am unable to get the variable `daily_expense` to accumulate when an expense is added a second time.

```
def take_input():
    daily_expense = 0
    inp = int(input("How much did you spend?: "))
    daily_expense += inp
    print(f"Total expenses = {daily_expense}")

    while True:
        x = input("Add another expense? Y/N: ").lower()
        if x == "y":
            take_input()
        elif x == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Please return a valid response")

def start_program():
    start = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()
    if start == "y":
        take_input()

start_program()
```

Comment: What do you mean by whenever the function is run? I run it once today and then I want to access information I entered tomorrow from a db?

Comment: If you want a value to persist in between times that you run a function, it needs to be saved *outside* the function (in this case, inside the `start_program` function would work). Otherwise, everything inside the function gets "reset" each time you run the function.

Comment: so instead of "saving" the value inside `take_input`, you would *return* the value from `take_input` to the calling function, and add it to a variable there.

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a potentially infinite loop. Everything *before* your `while` loop should simply be added to the *top of* the loop, and replace the recursive call with `continue`.

Comment: Hint: see where the code says `while True:`? Can you think of a way to put other code inside that loop, in order to get what you want, **rather than** making the recursive call? (Hint: how many times should `daily_expense = 0` happen - just once, or every time an expense is input? How many times should `daily_expense += inp` happen - just once, or every time an expense is input? How many times should an expense be input - just once, or multiple times? Therefore, which things should go inside the loop, and which should go outside?

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code

```
def take_input(daily_expense:int):
   
    inp = int(input("How much did you spend?: "))
    daily_expense += inp
    print(f"Total expenses = {daily_expense}")

    while True:
        x = input("Add another expense? Y/N: ").lower()
        if x == "y":
            take_input(daily_expense)
        elif x == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Please return a valid response")

def start_program():
    daily_expense = 0
    start = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()
    if start == "y":
        take_input(daily_expense)

start_program()
```

Comment: Thanks. After I input "n" after entering an expense, it seems that this code generates "Add another expense? Y/N" twice. Any idea how to get it to break after the first "n" is input?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently defining daily_expense inside of the function; which means every time take_input() is called, you are resetting daily_expense to 0.

Instead, you should either define daily_expense outside of the function so it will no longer be reset each time; or you should accumulate it all within the loop and then print the final value, like so:

```
    def take_input():
        daily_expense = 0

        more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

        while(more_expenses == "y"):
            inp = int(input("How much did you spend?: "))
            daily_expense += inp
            more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

            if(more_expenses == "n"):
                break
            elif(more_expenses == "y"):
                continue
            else:
                print("Please return a valid response")
                more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

        print(f"Total expenses = {daily_expense}")

    def start_program():
        take_input()

    start_program()
```

Edit:
Additional notes:

- Every time this function is called, the value resets again and reaccumulates.
- If you want to store this value in a database, then I recommend returning it and then using the returned value to update a database entry like so:

  ```
   def take_input():
       daily_expense = 0

       more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

       while(more_expenses == "y"):
           inp = int(input("How much did you spend?: "))
           daily_expense += inp
           more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

           if(more_expenses == "n"):
               break
           elif(more_expenses == "y"):
               continue
           else:
               print("Please return a valid response")
               more_expenses = input("Add expense? Y/N: ").lower()

       print(f"Total expenses = {daily_expense}")
       return daily_expense

   def start_program():
       save_this_number_to_db = take_input()

       # store save this number into database

   start_program()
  ```

Comment: Thanks. How can I add code so that if an incorrect input (not "y" or "n") is input (say they input a number rather than Y or N).

Comment: You can change the line in the else statement to reflect that :)

else:
             more_expenses = input("Please enter a valid number expense ").lower()

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get it to refer back to the question above? Don't I need a function of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop instead of recursion to continually process user input.

```py
def start_program():
    daily_expense = 0
    extra = ""
    while 1:
        x = input(f"Add {extra}expense? Y/N: ").lower()
        if x == "y":
            inp = int(input("How much did you spend?: "))
            daily_expense += inp
            print(f"Total expenses = {daily_expense}")
            extra = "another "
        elif x == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Please return a valid response")
```